Zookeeper Confluent Kafka 'Error opening file zookeeper-gc.log' when Running Confluent
I'm building a Kafka Application on Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2).
I'm using Zookeeper 3.5.8, confluent-6.1.0 and java openjdk version 17.0.12.
I successfully installed all the above platforms on WSL2, however, when I run the command confluent local services start, I get the error Error: ZooKeeper failed to start.
Then when I run the zookeeper-server-start command independently to see the error causing the failure, I get the error [error][logging] Error opening log file '/mnt/c/../confluent-6.1.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log': No such file or directory and another one Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Java is installed correctly in WSL2 and the JAVA_HOME path is also set correctly on WSL2 (I've tested it and it works).
What could be the issue causing this?
Zookeeper-server-start command:

$ bin/zookeeper-server-start etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties


Error Log:

[0.006s][error][logging] Error opening log file '/mnt/c/Windows/system32/confluent-6.1.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log': No such file or directory
[0.006s][logging] Initialization of output 'file=/mnt/c/Windows/system32/confluent-6.1.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log' using options 'filecount=10,filesize=100M' failed.
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*:file=/mnt/c/Windows/system32/confluent-6.1.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log:time,tags:filecount=10,filesize=100M', see error log for details.

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.


Zookeeper.properties:

# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0
# Disable the adminserver by default to avoid port conflicts.
# Set the port to something non-conflicting if choosing to enable this
admin.enableServer=false
# admin.serverPort=8080



Which version of zookeeper are you using  ? Do you run your starter from the WSL prompt ?

Zookeeper version 3.5.8

Yes am starting it in WSL2.

Official support of Java 17 came with Zookeeper 3.7, even if it mostly works. Did you try using another version of java like 11 or 8 ?

It came bundled with confluent-6.1.0 when installing. So I assumed it's supported.

But no I haven't tried it with 11 or 8.

Confluent Platform didn't add Java 17 support until latest versions... Use a newer Confluent Platform. Also, Zookeeper isn't needed anymore for Kafka, so why are you trying to run it?

Am a newbie to Confluent. True and true. Will migrate to KRaft.

The error isn't specific to Confluent. https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_download

Note - You should never place anything except DLL files in the System32 folder

Confluent Platform didn't add Java 17 support until the latest versions. Official support of Java 17 came with Zookeeper 3.7. I had to migrate to a newer Confluent Platform.
Also, Confluent decoupled Zookeeper for KRaft, which now manages consensus protocols for Kafka.
